# função $.Ajax() retornar valor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, undefined

esse é o codigo:

```
var res = VerFileRepetidoBancoAjax( "teste" );
console.log("res="+res);

function VerFileRepetidoBancoAjax( str ){
 $.ajax({
    url:    "caminho.",
    type:   "get",
    dataType:"json",
    data:   "dado="+ str,
    async: false,

    success: function( data ){
        return data;           
    }
});
}
```

Neste caso preciso do valor de retorno da função Ajax, que sempre retorna ***undefined***.
Esta ***função retorna um pequeno objeto Json*** que depois será manipulado em outros lugares.

Por hora, para resolver está questão usei uma variável publica, segue:

```
/* declaro uma variavel publica */
var res ;
VerFileRepetidoBancoAjax( "teste" );
console.log("res = "+res);

function VerFileRepetidoBancoAjax( str ){
 $.ajax({
    url:    "caminho.",
    type:   "get",
    dataType:"json",
    data:   "dado="+ str,
    async: false,

    success: function( data ){
        /* aqui coloca o OBJ dentro da variavel publica*/
        res = data;           
    }
});
}
```

Existe uma forma dentro da própria função $.ajax();

Comment: Estas a fazer uma chamada ajax para que outro tipo de linguagem? PHP? ASP? A partida o teu erro está na `url`, porque está a espera que envies o pedido para uma função, ou ficheiro, que por sua vez irá ter um return

Comment: Na verdade o Json retornado, será usado dentro do próprio javascript e a propósito a linguagem que estou usando é Java.

Answer (score 6):

Você esta retornando o data para dentro da função, mas não retorna nada para fora dela, tente assim:

```
var res = VerFileRepetidoBancoAjax( "teste" );
console.log("res="+res);

function VerFileRepetidoBancoAjax( str ){
 var retorno;
 $.ajax({
    url:    "caminho.",
    type:   "get",
    dataType:"json",
    data:   "dado="+ str,
    async: false,

    success: function( data ){
        retorno = data;           
    }
});
return retorno;
}
```

Comment: Muito bem observado, tks. Eu estava usando uma **variável publica** para causar o mesmo efeito que sua resposta me proporciona. Flw.

Comment: O segredo está aqui: ´sycr: false´, também apanhei bastante por causa deste mero detalhe =)

Comment: Requisições síncronas foram marcadas como depreciadas. Deveria evitar usá-las. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48011/nos-novos-navegadores-agora-n%C3%A3o-haver%C3%A1-mais-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-s%C3%ADncronas

Answer (score 3):

O valor retornado está no parâmetro `data` da sua função de *callback* em caso de sucesso:

```
success: function( data ){
    console.log("data ="+data );      
}
```

A chamada [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) em si é assíncrona por padrão (`async: true`), e a sua função `VerFileRepetidoBancoAjax` não está retornando nada.

Answer (score 2):

O uso de requisições ajax síncronas é desencorajado, provavelmente em seu console sairá algo como isso:
XMLHttpRequest síncrono não deve ser usado na thread principal devido a seus efeitos prejudiciais para a experiência de usuário. Para mais informações http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

O que pode ser feito  nesses casos é usar callback, sua função ficaria mais  ou menos assim:

```
function VerFileRepetidoBancoAjax( str, response, err ){
    $.ajax({
        url:    "caminho.",
        type:   "get",
        dataType:"json",
        data:   "dado="+ str,

        success: function( data ) {
            response(data);   
        },

        error: function (request, status, error) {
            err(request.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

E usaria ela da seguinte forma:

```
 VerFileRepetidoBancoAjax( "teste", function (response) {
      console.log(response);
 }, function (error) {
     console.log(error);
 });
```