# Nos novos navegadores agora não haverá mais requisições síncronas?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, assincronismo

Eu vi hoje no meu `Google Chrome`, atualizado para a versão  `40.0.2214.91`, uma mensagem que dizia

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

traduzindo:

> O Synchronous XMLHttpRequest no segmento principal é desencorajado por
>   causa de seus efeitos nocivos para a experiência do usuário final

Isso quer dizer que, para novos navegadores, as requisições via AJAX não terão mais a requisição síncrona.

Já devo começar mudar a forma de programar desde já, pensando em futuramente essa diretiva ser removida?

Comment: Excelente pergunta +1

Comment: Há anos usar requisições síncronas vem sendo desaconselhado, ainda antes do processo de *deprecation*, simplesmente pelo efeito negativo na experiência do usuário. Eu vi isso sendo insistentemente dito no SO em inglês pelo menos desde 2012. Mesmo assim, muita gente ainda insiste em usar. Boa atitude essa da equipe do Chrome de mostrar um aviso. E boa atitude sua em perguntar sobre o assunto :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

É, a ideia é essa. Veja a [especificação](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method):

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest outside of workers is in the process of being removed from the web platform as it has detrimental effects to the end user's experience. (This is a long process that takes many years.) Developers must not pass false for the async argument when the JavaScript global environment is a document environment. User agents are strongly encouraged to warn about such usage in developer tools and may experiment with throwing an InvalidAccessError exception when it occurs.

O que o navegador está fazendo é seguir a recomendação acima de avisar que este é um recurso que não deve ser usado. Ou use a requisição assíncrona ou faça isto em uma *thread* (*worker*).

Note que isto vai levar tanto tempo que pouca coisa feita hoje estará viva até lá. Coisas terríveis, bem piores que isto, que eram permitidas há 20 anos ainda funcionam dos navegadores de hoje.

Infelizmente não existem mais alertas. A imensa maioria dos desenvolvedores usam coisas que não deveriam aos montes e nem sabem disto. Não só em JS em navegadores, isto vale para muitas linguagens e funcionalidades diversas.

Se algo é considerado obsoleto, não deve mais ser usado em coisas novas e sempre que tiver a oportunidade de mudar algo existente, deve ser feito.

Claro que se não fizer não terá problemas por muito tempo, mas aí vai da postura de cada profissional e recursos (tempo principalmente, para modificar o existente, embora seja algo rápido neste caso) que cada um tem.

Mas se pensar bem fazer a requisição síncrona não faz muito sentido. Se é para fazer isto, chame a página. Muitas pessoas acham que AJAX é uma linguagem de programação. É apenas uma técnica bem específica usando `XMLHTTPRequest` e o `A` significa assíncrona (Asynchronous Javascript And XML). Só que ninguém usa XML mais :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: estou me a tornar um comentador cronico teu :D
Não fazia ideia disso do "**A**synchronous **J**avascript **a**nd **X**ML" Nunca tive curiosidade em saber o que queria dizer...

Comment: Sempre bem-vindo.

Comment: Hoje a sigla deveria ser AJAJ (**A**synchronous **J**avascript **A**nd **J**SON) ao invés de AJAX (**A**synchronous **J**avascript **A**nd **X**ML), já que "ninguém usa XML mais" para essa finalidade, onde o JSON passou a ser utilizado, quase como padrão. =)