# Existem alguma maneira de detectar se existe alguma chamada assincrona sendo rodada?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Eu preciso rodar um loop de chamadas assíncronas, porém elas não podem rodar simultaneamente, tenho que aguardar o final para rodar outra. Só que eu não tenho controle sobre essa chamada([É uma função js do Sharepoint CSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907(v=office.15).aspx)).

Então eu a príncipio a minha idéia é só detectar se uma chamada já esta rodando. Se estiver rodando eu vou testando de novo até que não exista mais chamada rodando, e ai sim eu continuo o loop.

Mais ou menos assim a ideia:

```
function chamarAjax(){
    blablabla();

    if(blablabla()){
        continuarLoop = false;
    }
}

if(!ajaxIsRunning){
  if(continuarLoop){
      chamarAjax();
  }
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas serviu para o que você queria?

Comment: Ainda não. Todas elas estão supondo que eu estou usando a chamada tradicional do ajax, via $.ajax e indicando para que eu coloque instruções dentro do success ou complete. Mas como mencionado na pergunta, estou utilizando uma chamada de uma função do sharepoint(executeQueryAsync).

Comment: Mencionei a função, mas o ideal era que houvesse alguma solucao genérica, pois poderia ser util para muito mais pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

Conte quantas vezes você executa uma solicitação AJAX, e, em seguida, contar o número de vezes que você já viu uma chamada para o callback concluída. Uma vez que o retorno de chamada completada é igual ao número de vezes que você emitil chamadas ajax, você saberá que o que está rodando.

```
var total = arr.length;
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     $.ajax({
        // outras opções 
        complete: function(){
            count++;
            if(count == total){ 
                // tudo consumado!
            }
        }
     });
}
```

Note que eu uso o callback "completo", não é "sucesso", uma vez que se um dos pedidos falharem, mas 'completo'. Além disso, eu declarei o valor esperado em 'total' em primeiro lugar. Isso é para evitar o improvável (embora tecnicamente possível) cenário de ter todos os pedidos pendentes de ajax terminando antes de você postar todos eles, e, portanto, ter uma contagem.

Answer (score 1):

Você simplesmente pode encadear suas chamadas, para somente chamar a próxima ao ter finalizado a anterior, não sei se isso atende as suas necessidades, mais é uma maneira:

```js
$(function(){
    $.ajax({ // request 1
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
    }).always(function() {
        console.log("Complete 1");
        $.ajax({ // request 2
            type: "POST",
            url: "some2.php",
            data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
        }).always(function() {
            console.log("Complete 2");
            $.ajax({ // request 3
                type: "POST",
                url: "some3.php",
                data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
            }).always(function() {
                console.log("Complete 3");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver utilizando jQuery, poderá pegar o número de requisições Ajax ativas através da função `$.active`, essa é uma função que o jQuery usa internamente, mas não mencionado na documentação oficial. Não há problema em utilizá-lo.

Veja esse exemplo encontrado no [Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js).

```
function checkPendingRequest() 
{
    if ($.active > 0) {
      // existe requisições pendentes
    }
    else {

      // não há requisições pendentes
    }
};
```

Referências: [Fonte¹](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8651485/1608936), [Fonte²](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25520719/1608936)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode setar a propriedade `async` do `AJAX` como `false`, é uma propriedade que já existe no próprio `AJAX` do `JQuery`

---

Por padrão, o método `jQuery.Ajax` vem com o parâmetro `async` setado como `true`. Isso significa que as requisições `assíncronas` estão habilitadas. Ás vezes, é necessário que enlacemos as requisições `Ajax`, ou seja, realizar uma requisição `Ajax` somente quando a anterior terminar, e aí sim, realizar a próxima.

Mais ou menos desse modo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Detalhe pra uma pergunta levantada na semana passada pelo usuário @WallaceMaxters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48011/nos-novos-navegadores-agora-n%C3%A3o-haver%C3%A1-mais-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-s%C3%ADncronas)

**Ou seja, as requisições `síncronas` estão sendo desencorajadas, porém ainda dá pra usar desse modo, e por um bom tempo ainda será possível**

Desse modo seu Ajax poderia ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
jQuery.ajax({ /*Requisição 1*/
  url: 'index.html',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    jQuery('.destino').html(data);

    jQuery.ajax({ /*Requisição 2*/
      url: 'index2.html',
      async: false,
      success: function() {
         alert(jQuery("#campo").val());
     }

 }
});
```