# Como fazer para que uma function espere o resultado do $http?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou tendo problema com o seguinte código:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/publicacao/',
    data: $scope.publicacao,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}).success(function(publicacao) {
    $scope.publicacao = publicacao.data;
    console.log($scope.publicacao);

    //Upload de imagem
    if ($scope.tipo == 'imagem') {
        var arquivo = $("#imagem")[0].files[0];
        var nomeArquivo = $("#imagem")[0].files[0].name;

        UploadFileService.uploadArquivo('/upload', arquivo, nomeArquivo , publicacao.codigoPubl , 'imagem');
    }

    //Upload de arquivo
    else if ($scope.tipo == 'arquivo') {
        var arquivo = $("#arquivo")[0].files[0];
        var nomeArquivo = $("#arquivo")[0].files[0].name;

        UploadFileService.uploadArquivo('/upload', arquivo, nomeArquivo , publicacao.codigoPubl , 'arquivo');
    }

    $location.path('/timelines/' + $routeParams.codTime);
    $window.location.reload();
    $scope.addSucessoMsg();
}).error (function(erro) {
    console.log('Erro ao adicionar a publicação: ' + erro);
    $scope.addErroMsg();
});
```

Depois que a publicação é salva no servidor, preciso chamar o serviço `UploadFileService` para enviar uma imagem ou um arquivo pro servidor, enviando o código para que a imagem ou o arquivo possa ser linkado com a respectiva publicação.

A ideia é fazer com que a chamada do serviço `UploadFileService` espere até que o $http retorne com a publicação. Comecei a mexer com JavaScript e AngularJS faz pouco tempo e estou com dúvida em como fazer chained promises ([Requisições síncronas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76321/requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-s%C3%ADncronas)), li alguns posts em português e em inglês mas não sei como usar isso pra resolver este problema.

Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Qual o problema que você está tendo?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o `$http` faz uma chamada assíncrona, o que em teoria permite que o código continue sua execução enquanto ele não termina, certo? O problema que eu imagino é o seguinte, é possível de alguma forma que as chamadas do serviço `UploadFileService` sejam executadas antes de o `$http` ter recebido a resposta do servidor? Até o momento durante os meus testes não ocorreu de a publicação ficar como `undefined` e dar erro, mas quero poder evitar que isso ocorra. Comecei a ler sobre as promises faz pouco tempo, então ainda tenho dúvidas em como elas funcionam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O serviço `$http` é uma função que leva um único argumento - um objeto de configuração - que é usado para gerar uma solicitação HTTP e retorna uma **promessa** ([código fonte](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L382)).

```
$http({
    //objeto de configuração
})
//...
```

No entanto, ele usa uma abstração de `$q` ([documentação](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)) e porque é uma abstração ele renomeia as funções de callback. Em vez de `.then` e `.catch` é `.success` e `.error`.

```
$http({
    //objeto de configuração
}).success(function(data) {
    //requisição HTTP executada com sucesso
}).error (function(error) {
    //algo correu mal
});
```

O serviço `$q` por sua vez ajuda você a executar funções de forma assíncrona e usar seus valores de retorno (ou exceções) quando eles são processados.

Ou seja, tudo que está dentro da função de callback definida no método `.success` será executado após a conclusão da requisição HTTP, caso a mesma seja executada com sucesso, caso contrário será executado a função de callback definida no método `.error`.

Porém a explicação acima é válida somente para as versões que ainda implementam os métodos `success` e `error`, que analisando o código inserido na pergunta, é o seu caso.

Como bem observado pelo [@OnoSendai](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180728/como-fazer-para-que-uma-function-espere-o-resultado-do-http/180850#180850), tenha atenção que os métodos `success` e `error` como callbacks de `$http` foram declarados descontinuados. Em vez disso, use o método `then` passando como argumento as funções de sucesso e erro.

```
$http({
     //objeto de configuração
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    //requisição HTTP executada com sucesso
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    //ocorreu um erro
});
```

Comment: O uso do success e do error feitos dessa forma, se não me falha a memória, são para as versões 1.4 pra baixo. As versões atuais ele usa o .then passando no parâmetro 2 funções que serão os callbacks da promise.

Comment: @PauloGustavo foi o que ele colocou na pergunta, pelo menos é o que está no código, então expliquei o motivo de ser usado esses 2 métodos, o que para mim fez sentido explicar.

Answer (score 2):

Aguarde o retorno da operação HTTP em uma função de *callback*, que [de acordo com a documentação do serviço $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) deverá estar presente no primeiro parâmetro do método `then()` do objeto retornado:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/umaUrlQualquer'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {

    // este callback é chamado assincronamente
    // quanto a resposta está disponível

  }, function errorCallback(response) {

    // chamado assincronamente quando um erro ocorre,
    // ou quando o servidor responde com um código de erro.

  });
```

Caso necessário, [utilize promessas em cadeia para processar chamadas HTTP em cascata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76330/1897).

Observação: **Não utilize** `success` e `error` como *callbacks* de `$http`. A documentação da versão 1.5.9 possui o seguinte anúncio:

> **Deprecation Notice**
>
> > The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Que se traduz como:

> **Aviso de descontinuidade**
>
> > Os métodos de *callback* `success` e `error` [do serviço $http] foram declarados descontinuados. Em vez disso, use o método padrão. Se `$httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions` estiver definido como `false`, então esses métodos irão lançar o erro `$http/legacy`.

A versão 1.6.0 já não inclui a notícia, o que me faz acreditar que os métodos foram retirados.

Fonte: https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.9/docs/api/ng/service/$http