# Encadeamento de requisições assíncronas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, assincronismo

Preciso fazer o processamento assíncrono de série de dados (envio de dados a um servidor REST) e, somente ao final de todas as requisições, preciso realizar outra função.

Como posso controlar esse fluxo se cada requisição é assíncrona?

O que eu preciso é algo mais ou menos assim:

```
for (var i=0; l<objetos.length; i++){
  var o=objetos[i];
  Enviar($q, o).then(function(){})
}
//ao término de todas as requisições acima, disparar um novo evento...
```

Comment: Se você tem todos os dados em `objetos`, porque não enviá-los de uma só vez? Não sobrecarrega a sua página com várias requests. Não é uma boa prática.

Comment: Se for ajax há uma configuração chamada: async, coloca o valor async: false, e depois sim tens varias funções em caso de sucesso e de fail.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown estou enviando um arquivo e o servidor só aceita um file por vez.

Comment: @Wilson estou enviando o arquivo com o `cordovaFileTransfer.upload()`

Comment: @Wilson- É melhor evitar isso a todo custo, não só por travar a interface de usuário, mas também porque [deixará de ser suportado pelos navegadores](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48011/74).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que o certo seria iniciar uma request apenas quando outra terminar:

```
var enviarArquivo = function(indice)
{
    Enviar($q, objetos[indice]).then(function()
    {
        if (++indice < objetos.length)
        {
            enviarArquivo(indice);
        }
        else
        {
            // Processo finalizado
        }
    })
}

// Chamada inicial
enviarArquivo(0);
```

Dessa forma uma request não inicia sem que a outra tenha terminado e você consegue saber quando a última acabou.

Comment: Só não ficou mais perfeito porque a condição do if deveria ser `if (++indice < (objetos.length))` ;). Obrigado!

Comment: Solução inteligente, +1

Comment: @NilsonUehara ok, valeu pela correção. Fiz de cabeça, achei que estava certo.

Answer (score 4):

você pode usar o [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) para esperar todas as promise

```
var promises = objetos.map(function (o) {
    return Enviar($q, o);
});

$q.all(promises).then(function(){});
```

lembrando que o [.then()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises) retorna uma nova promessa, neste caso você pode executar uma ação ao termino do envio de cada arquivo e uma ação ao termino do envio de todos os arquivos.

```
var promises = objetos.map(function (o) {
    var promise = Enviar($q, o);
    return promise.then(function(){});
});

$q.all(promises).then(function(){});
```

Comment: Se for mesmo angular, é a melhor solução.

Comment: Ah, retiro o que eu disse. Parece que ele precisa mesmo **encadear** as requisições, e esse método não garante isso.

Comment: A resposta do @DontVoteMeDown resolve meu problema além de me garantir o encadeamento correto. De qualquer forma, a sua solução também me será muito útil, por isso já lhe dei um voto positivo. Obrigado!