# Usando Sqlite no Android com Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova, sqlite

Galera, to com um pequeno problema... 
Estou fazendo uma aplicação e estou usando o sqlite no android para salvar uma cópia do meu banco de dados, até aqui está tudo bem, está funcionando, está copiando os dados o único problema que encontrei é a seguinte.

Para deixar mais claro estou colocando o trecho do meu código que "popula" o meu banco de dados sqlite.

```
var _db;

var DataBase = {

    url : 'http://192.168.1.26:9075/',

    //construtor 
    init: function(){        

        try{
            _db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase(
                {
                    name: "Banco29.db",
                    location: 0 //1
                });
        }catch(e){
            Funcoes.alerta(e,'Erro');
        }

    },

    popularTabela: function(tbl,unidade){
            var nome = tbl.split('.');
            myApp.showPreloader('Atualizando a tabela: '+nome[1]+ ', Isso pode levar alguns minutos, não feche o aplicativo');

            console.log("Populando: "+tbl);
            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: DataBase.url+"procDataBase.php?acao=PopularDados&tabela="+tbl+"&unidade="+unidade,
                    complete:function(){
                     // myApp.hidePreloader();
                    },               
                    success: function (json) {
                        var json = JSON.parse(json);
                        if(json.result == true){
                            var tamanho = json.dados.length;

                           //if(nome[1] === 'ocupacao'){ console.log(JSON.stringify(json)); }

                            for (var i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {                    
                                if(json.dados[i] !== null && json.dados[i] !== 'null' && typeof(json.dados[i]) !== 'object'){
                                    //console.log(json.dados[i]);
                                    _db.executeSql(json.dados[i], [], function (tx, res){

                                    }, function (t,e){
                                        Funcoes.alerta('Error: '+nome[1]+' '+e.message,'Aviso');
                                    });
                                }
                            }; 
                        }   

                        myApp.hidePreloader();               

                    },error: function(){
                       Funcoes.alerta('Erro para atualizar tabela: '+nome[1]+ ' atualize manualmente a mesma.','Erro');
                       myApp.hidePreloader();  
                    }
            },"json");

        }
}
```

Eu faço uma requisição `$.ajax` no meu servidor e ele me retorna um array de insert, estes insert são os dados que estou copiando do meu banco de dados online, tem tabela por exemplo que possui 5 mil registros, aqui que entra o problema, na hora que inicia uma requisição `$.ajax` eu coloco uma mensagem de "loading" exibindo para o usuário e dentro da função "sucesso" do `$.ajax` eu coloco para ele inserir as query que minha requisição retornou e no final coloco para esconder a mensagem `myApp.hidePreloader();`, e aqui está o meu problema, na hora que a requisição com o servidor termina ele já esconde a mensagem de Loading porém o aplicativo continua trabalhando e inserindo as query, logicamente ele deveria esconder a mensagem de loading só depois que finalizasse todos os processos não é? 
E meu problema está sendo neste ponto, porque preciso que a mensagem só "esconda" após finalizar, como disse tem uma tabela que tem 5 mil registros e até terminar de inserir o aplicativo fica travado e a pessoa não consegue mexer.

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no meu post http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84194/encadeamento-de-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ass%C3%ADncronas

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas acho que você está deixando seu aplicativo um tanto inseguro. Mesmo sendo um mobile app, existe como debugar através do chrome://inspect e qualquer pessoa vai poder ver as requisições que estão sendo feitas, logo saber exatamente como seu banco de dados funciona e até mudar dados manualmente. Te aconselho a salvar no cliente apenas os dados triviais e não uma tabela inteira

Comment: Alem disso qual outra sugestão que você tem para melhorar a segurança? Agradeço a dica!

Answer (score 1):

No callback de success do `_db.executeSql` você pode verificar se o último registro foi processado e então esconder o seu loading.

```
// Uso de função imediata (Immediately Invoked Function)
!function db_success(index){
    _db.executeSql(json.dados[index], [], function (tx, res){
        if (index === (tamanho - 1)) {
            Funcoes.alerta('Último registro foi processado');
            myApp.hidePreloader();
        }
    })
}(i), 
function (t,e){
    Funcoes.alerta('Error: '+nome[1]+' '+e.message,'Aviso');
});
```

Comment: Obrgado pela dica mas já tentei assim o problema é o seguinte, primeiro ele está lendo todo o for(), e depois ele insere, por exemplo se eu colocar da maneira que vc citou a var i já está com o tamanho maximo, porque? Porque ele primeiro lê todo o for() e depois ele entra no bloco do _db.executeSQL() ... Para ilustrar melhor eu fiz um debug.. coloquei o console.log(i) dentro do for, e outro dentro do result de sucesso, ai eu percebi que ele vai exibindo tudo no for e depois por ultimo ele executa a inserção...

Comment: Não atentei ao laço com função assíncrona. Corrigi o código usando uma função imediata. O valor de `i`  já tá no máximo por quê a chamada à `_db.executeSql` é assíncrona, por isso ela retorna imediatamente e o `i` chega ao valor máximo antes do processamento terminar.

Comment: Hmm, então agora apareceu este erro..

Uncaught ReferenceError: tx is not defined -- Linha 221, e nesta linha 221 está este trecho...

(function (tx, res, index){
                                    if (index === (tamanho - 1)) {
                                        console.log("Populando: "+tbl);
                                        console.log('Último registro foi processado');
                                        myApp.hidePreloader();
                                    }
                                })(tx, res, i),

Comment: Joguei a função pra fora da chamada do `executeSql`, mas não tem como eu rodar o código aqui pra verificar. Acredito que não vá ocorrer o `tx is not defined` dessa forma.

Comment: Então, eu coloquei está função dentro do loop, este é o certo? No caso agora ele está dando erro falando que está faltando um fechamento de chaves no código...  Outra coisa, a variavel dentro do parenteses da função (index) eu preciso por o a váriavel i ? ou não precisa? quero agradecer de novo a sua ajuda!

Comment: Então, faltou fechar um parenteses, já corrigi o código. O parâmetro `index` da função `db_success(index)` vai assumir o valor de `i`, não precisa mudar nada ali.

Comment: agora apareceu o erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) esse erro está na ultima linha do código que é o }); a function (t, e) não deveria ficar dentro do _db ? porque ele mostra um erro caso a inserção não for certo...

Comment: Eu mudei o codigo pra essa forma, http://jsfiddle.net/bpaacsh1/
Está correto?

Comment: Sim. Eu criei um fork http://jsfiddle.net/1nya4vc2/ em que eu só mudei a notação da função (troquei o `!` por parenteses).

Comment: Tulio, coloquei, mesmo assim da erro de fechamento de parenteses..  eu editei o meu código principal, coloquei ele completo pra você ver. Estou usando funções anonimas, não sei se tem algo a ver isto...