# Erro Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Quando utilizo este código em meu arquivo, ocorre um erro no log, e acaba dando problemas em outras chamadas javascript.

Arquivo da página atual (o javascript que dá problema está no final):

```html
<html>
<head>

  <script src="../../assets/js/common-scripts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
      $.ajax('indicadores.php?id_indicador=1').done(function(data) {
        $("#collapse1").html(data);
      });
    );
  </script>

</head>

  <body>

  <section id="container" >
    <section id="main-content">
      <section class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 main-chart">
            <h3 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Indicadores</h3>
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" id="collapse11">Teste</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse active">
                <!-- Carrega conteúdo do arquivo pa_nr_atendimentos.php através de Javascript-->
                </div>
              </div>      
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

O último script chama o conteúdo que está no arquivo `indicadores.php`:

```
<!--Com esta chamada apresenta o erro citado. Se eu tirar não apresenta o erro, porém, o conteúdo abaixo sai desconfigurado pela falta do arquivo.-->
  <script src="../../assets/js/common-scripts.js"></script>

  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row mt">
      <!--AQUI HTML COM GRÁFICOS QUE SE BASEIAM NO ARQUIVO COMMOM-SCRIPTS.JS-->
    </div> 
  </div>
```

ERRO APRESENTADO NO CONSOLE:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Isto ocorre quando carrego o conteúdo presente na página `indicadores.php` através de uma chamada em ajax assíncrono, executada na página atual. Alguém sabe como posso resolver?

Conteúdo de common-scripts.js: http://fiddle.jshell.net/tamh2mo5/:

```
/*---LEFT BAR ACCORDION----*/
$(function() {
    $('#nav-accordion').dcAccordion({
        eventType: 'click',
        autoClose: true,
        saveState: true,
        disableLink: true,
        speed: 'slow',
        showCount: false,
        autoExpand: true,
//        cookie: 'dcjq-accordion-1',
        classExpand: 'dcjq-current-parent'
    });
});

var Script = function () {


//    sidebar dropdown menu auto scrolling

    jQuery('#sidebar .sub-menu > a').click(function () {
        var o = ($(this).offset());
        diff = 250 - o.top;
        if(diff>0)
            $("#sidebar").scrollTo("-="+Math.abs(diff),500);
        else
            $("#sidebar").scrollTo("+="+Math.abs(diff),500);
    });



//    sidebar toggle

    $(function() {
        function responsiveView() {
            var wSize = $(window).width();
            if (wSize <= 768) {
                $('#container').addClass('sidebar-close');
                $('#sidebar > ul').hide();
            }

            if (wSize > 768) {
                $('#container').removeClass('sidebar-close');
                $('#sidebar > ul').show();
            }
        }
        $(window).on('load', responsiveView);
        $(window).on('resize', responsiveView);
    });

    $('.fa-bars').click(function () {
        if ($('#sidebar > ul').is(":visible") === true) {
            $('#main-content').css({
                'margin-left': '0px'
            });
            $('#sidebar').css({
                'margin-left': '-210px'
            });
            $('#sidebar > ul').hide();
            $("#container").addClass("sidebar-closed");
        } else {
            $('#main-content').css({
                'margin-left': '210px'
            });
            $('#sidebar > ul').show();
            $('#sidebar').css({
                'margin-left': '0'
            });
            $("#container").removeClass("sidebar-closed");
        }
    });

// custom scrollbar
    $("#sidebar").niceScroll({styler:"fb",cursorcolor:"#4ECDC4", cursorwidth: '3', cursorborderradius: '10px', background: '#404040', spacebarenabled:false, cursorborder: ''});

    $("html").niceScroll({styler:"fb",cursorcolor:"#4ECDC4", cursorwidth: '6', cursorborderradius: '10px', background: '#404040', spacebarenabled:false,  cursorborder: '', zindex: '1000'});

// widget tools

    jQuery('.panel .tools .fa-chevron-down').click(function () {
        var el = jQuery(this).parents(".panel").children(".panel-body");
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass("fa-chevron-down")) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
            el.slideUp(200);
        } else {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
            el.slideDown(200);
        }
    });

    jQuery('.panel .tools .fa-times').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).parents(".panel").parent().remove();
    });


//    tool tips

    $('.tooltips').tooltip();

//    popovers

    $('.popovers').popover();



// custom bar chart

    if ($(".custom-bar-chart")) {
        $(".bar").each(function () {
            var i = $(this).find(".value").html();
            $(this).find(".value").html("");
            $(this).find(".value").animate({
                height: i
            }, 2000)
        })
    }


}();
```

Com o common-scripts.js no arquivo indicadores.php:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Sem o common-scripts.js no arquivo indicadores.pho:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Isto ocorre mesmo common-scripts.js já tendo sido carregado anteriormente na página atual.

Versão do jQuery: 1.8.3

Comment: acho que tem a ver com isto -  async: true. Porém, não consegui resolver. Alguma dica?

Comment: Não parece que o warning está vindo deste snippet da pergunta, uma vez que o jQuery nunca faz requests síncronas por padrão. Este alerta é exibido quando uma requisição XMLHttpRequest é aberta com o parâmetro `async` como falso, [exemplo](http://jsbin.com/bupatawoto/edit?html,js) (veja o alerta no console).

Comment: E como eu poderia resolver? Você saberia me ajudar?

Comment: O primeiro passo seria identificar qual script está fazendo a chamada ajax síncrona

Comment: Eu consigo identificar que é no momento em que chama 'load' conforme citado na pergunta. Pois se eu tirar este código funciona corretamente.

Comment: Sei que ocorre o erro no momento em que ocorre o método 'load' do  jquery

Comment: Achei este post: http://tedk.com.br/blog/html/carregar-uma-pagina-dentro-de-uma-div-com-ajax/ talvez tenha algo que possa ajudar na resolução do problema, porém, não sei como aplicar em meu código

Comment: Nessa pagina `indicadores.php` faz outra requisição (via Ajax)? Tenho quase certeza que está dando conflito com outra requisição.

Comment: ocorre o erro na página indicadores.php se deixar esta requisição: 
  <script src="../../assets/js/common-scripts.js"></script>. Caso tire esta linha funciona perfeitamente

Comment: O problema é que se eu tira-la o conteúdo que estou carregando desconfigura.

Comment: Pergunta duplicada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48011/nos-novos-navegadores-agora-n%C3%A3o-haver%C3%A1-mais-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-s%C3%ADncronas

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Não acho que seja duplicada desta, pois o problema é com o uso do Ajax, apesar de ambos serem o mesmo problema, a solução na pergunta que linkou não ajudará a resolver o problema que na verdade deve ser resolvido com o jQuery (por exemplo usando o `$.ajaxSetup`). Acredito que são relacionadas mas não duplicada :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Acho que não. A sua pergunta é sobre o aspecto teórico, é sobre a proibição do AJAX síncrono em si. Lá você está perguntando se você deve mudar a forma de programar, mas você não abordou lá como identificar os pontos que o AJAX síncrono ocorre e nem como eliminá-los após identificados, que é o que ocorre nesta pergunta aqui.

Comment: Ok, galerinha. ;)

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto deixa essa inclusão `<script src="../../assets/js/common-scripts.js"></script>` na pagina onde vc faz o load. E retire do `indicadores.php`

Comment: Eu tenho ela na página onde faz o load, mas após carregar o conteúdo de indicadores.php é como se ela sumisse e preciso desta forma carregar novamente lá

Comment: Não entendi muito bem? Afinal pra que vc usa essa js?

Comment: É do próprio template que baixei. Ela faz funcionar uns gráficos na tela. Na página onde faz o load já tem carregado o arquivo JS, mas se eu não carregar também em indicadores.php os gráficos deixam de funcionar

Comment: Testa num browser mais antigo. Chrome versão 20, IE10, etc. Acho que o jQuery está usando alguma função do XMLHttpRequest que não é mais suportada. Se funfar num browser mais antigo, deve ser a causa.

Comment: Em browser mais antigo funcionou. Não sei o que pode ser

Comment: Eu não entendi o motivo dos graficos em relação a duvida, outra coisa o seu código não pode ser reproduzido, você colocou o commo-js, mas não colocou o jquery no seu html, isto da a entender que este não é o teu código que esta com problema, já que se você não incluir o jquery.js o problema seria outro na execução do javascript.

Comment: Cara tenho o mesmo problema. Conseguiu resolver ?

Answer (score 9):

## 1. AJAX assíncrono

O que você está usando (por meio do método `.load`) é o AJAX síncrono. Ao invés disso, use o AJAX assíncrono assim:

```js
$.ajax("indicadores.php?id_indicador=2").done(function(data) {
    $("#collapse1").html(data);
});
```

Note que há algumas diferenças:

- No AJAX síncrono, que é o que o `.load` faz, a página vai congelar totalmente, enquanto uma requisição é enviada ao servidor e só vai descongelar após receber a resposta do servidor. Enquanto o navegador espera o servidor responder, a página fica completamente congelada e inoperante, o que é péssimo para a experiência do usuário, ainda mais se a resposta do servidor demorar para ser carregada.
- No AJAX assíncrono, a execução continua logo após como se nada tivesse acontecido e o corpo do callback no `.done` só vai ser executado bem depois.

Desta forma, este código síncrono:

```js
alert("Antes");
$("#collapse1").load('indicadores.php?id_indicador=2');
alert("Depois");
```

O usuário vai ver o alert `Antes`, a página congelada, o conteúdo baixado do servidor vai aparecer e finalmente o alert `Depois`. Nesta ordem.

Isso é diferente do que ocorre com esse código assíncrono:

```js
alert("Antes");
$.ajax("indicadores.php?id_indicador=2").done(function(data) {
    alert("Surpresa");
    $("#collapse1").html(data);
});
alert("Depois");
```

O usuário vai ver o alert `Antes` e o alert `Depois` logo em seguida. A página vai ficar rodando normalmente por um curto espaço de tempo, quando de repente o alert `Surpresa` aparece e o conteúdo dinâmico do servidor surge.

Portanto, tenha cuidado se você tiver isso:

```js
$("#collapse1").load('indicadores.php?id_indicador=2');
var x = xpto($("#collapse1"));
var y = blabla(x);
```

Pois isso daqui não vai funcionar:

```js
$.ajax("indicadores.php?id_indicador=2").done(function(data) {
    $("#collapse1").html(data);
});
var x = xpto($("#collapse1"));
var y = blabla(x);
```

E o que você vai ter que usar é isso:

```js
$.ajax("indicadores.php?id_indicador=2").done(function(data) {
    $("#collapse1").html(data);
    var x = xpto($("#collapse1"));
    var y = blabla(x);
});
```

## 2. Tags `<script>` no `<body>`

As tags `<script>` com atributo `src` dentro do `<body>` também podem causar problemas (se estiver dentro do `<head>` não há problema). O motivo é que no meio do carregamento da página, quando a página já renderizou pela metade, o navegador é obrigado a parar e baixar um script do servidor, ocasionando o mesmo problema do AJAX síncrono.

Para exemplificar, veja este exemplo. Nele há três tags `<script>`. Duas delas estão ok, enquanto que uma causa este problema:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Título da página</title>

        <!--
            Esta tag <script> está ok, pois não está no <body>, e sim no <head>.
            Neste momento, o navegador ainda não começou a carregar a página propriamente
            dita, ele está apenas baixando os recursos necessários para fazer isso.
        -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="xpto1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

        <!--
            Esta tag <script> também está ok, pois não usa o atributo src.
            O javascript já está aqui, e portanto o navegador não vai precisar abrir uma
            nova requisição para baixá-lo.
        -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("script 2");
        </script>

        <p>Consectetuer adispiting elit</p>

        <!--
            Esta tag <script> é um problema!
            Ela vai forçar o navegador a parar o carregamento da página na metade para
            carregar o script do servidor.
        -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="xpto2.js"></script>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

E se dentro desta página eu baixar, via AJAX assíncrono, o `indicadores.php` com código HTML?

Primeiramente, **este código HTML será apenas um fragmento de uma HTML, e não uma HTML completa** (veja mais abaixo sobre isso). Desta forma, vamos supor que o fragmento HTML seja assim:

```html
<div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xpto3.js"></script>
    <span>Consectetuer adispiting elit</span>
</div>
```

Neste caso, o `<script>` que está lá vai te trazer problemas. Pois o navegador vai baixar este HTML de forma assíncrona (até aí tudo bem) e então vai ter que baixar o javascript de forma síncrona, e daí teremos o problema.

Uma forma de resolver isso é baixar este outro código também de forma assíncrona:

```html
<div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax("xpto3.js").done(function(data) {
            eval(data);
        });
    </script>
    <span>Consectetuer adispiting elit</span>
</div>
```

E isso dever resolver o problema. Entretanto, talvez ainda não seja a melhor solução, pois ainda estaremos fazendo duas requisições AJAX ao servidor para baixar o conteúdo, sendo que poderíamos usar uma só. Neste caso, a solução seria usar um server-side include (note o código PHP inline):

```html
<div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!-- O arquivo PHP incluído abaixo contém/gera código javascript. -->
        <?php include 'xpto3.php'; ?>
    </script>
    <span>Consectetuer adispiting elit</span>
</div>
```

E também vale ressaltar que carregar javascripts dentro de trechos de HTML trazidos por AJAX pode ser um tanto estranho. Talvez, o melhor seja simplesmente incluir todos os javascripts necessários no `<head>` da página principal, ainda mais se for um conteúdo estático como isso daqui:

```html
<!-- Deve ser colocado dentro do <head>. -->
<script src="../../assets/js/common-scripts.js"></script>
```

## 3. E se o fragmento for uma HTML completa?

Vamos supor que o que você baixe por AJAX seja isso:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!--Com esta chamada apresenta o erro citado. Se eu tirar não apresenta o erro, porém, o conteúdo abaixo sai desconfigurado pela falta do arquivo.-->
  <script src="../../assets/js/common-scripts.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row mt">
      <!--AQUI HTML COM GRÁFICOS QUE SE BASEIAM NO ARQUIVO COMMOM-SCRIPTS.JS-->
    </div> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Isso não é uma boa ideia, porque a sua HTML no final do carregamento ficaria assim:

```html
<html>
<head>

  <script src="../../assets/js/common-scripts.js"></script>

</head>

  <body>

  <section id="container" >
    <section id="main-content">
      <section class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 main-chart">
            <h3 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Indicadores</h3>
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" id="collapse11">Teste</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse active">
<html>
<head>
  <!--Com esta chamada apresenta o erro citado. Se eu tirar não apresenta o erro, porém, o conteúdo abaixo sai desconfigurado pela falta do arquivo.-->
  <script src="../../assets/js/common-scripts.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row mt">
      <!--AQUI HTML COM GRÁFICOS QUE SE BASEIAM NO ARQUIVO COMMOM-SCRIPTS.JS-->
    </div> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
                </div>
              </div>      
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>

  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax('indicadores.php?id_indicador=1').done(function(data) {
    $("#collapse1"+).html(data);
  });
</script>
```

Observe que temos duas vezes a tag `<html>`, o que é ilegal (a segunda tag `<html>` está dentro do `<body>`), e também estamos importanto duas vezes o mesmo javascript, o que também não é boa ideia. Além disso, o erro vai voltar porque o `<script>` da página baixada, embora esteja dentro do `<head>` desta página, também está dentro do `<body>` da página externa. Não é permitido em `<html>` se ter uma página dentro da outra desta forma.

O melhor neste caso, seria forçar que o carregamento fosse de apenas um trecho de HTML. Uma forma de se fazer isso é tornar a segunda página em apenas isso:

```html
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row mt">
      <!--AQUI HTML COM GRÁFICOS QUE SE BASEIAM NO ARQUIVO COMMOM-SCRIPTS.JS-->
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Observe que não há nada de `<html>`, nem de `<head>`, nem de `<body>` e nem de `<script>` nisto, pois se trata de um fragmento de HTML, e não de um HTML completo. Estas coisas que não estão nesta página interna já existem na página externa e portanto não só não são necessárias na página interna, como colocá-las lá é uma violação do padrão do HTML.

## 4. Onde colocar a tag `<script>`?

Há mais uma outra violação importante da HTML: **Você NUNCA deveria ter NADA após a tag de fechamento `</html>`.** Entretanto, você colocou um `<script>` lá, depois do `</html>`. Isso é absolutamente ilegal no padrão HTML (mas o navegador quer ser bonzinho e tolera essas coisas). O correto é tentar colocar os scripts no `<head>` sempre que possível:

```html
<html>
<head>

  <script src="../../assets/js/common-scripts.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax('indicadores.php?id_indicador=1').done(function(data) {
        $("#collapse1").html(data);
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

  <body>

  <section id="container" >
    <section id="main-content">
      <section class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 main-chart">
            <h3 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Indicadores</h3>
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" id="collapse11">Teste</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse active">
                <!-- Carrega conteúdo do arquivo pa_nr_atendimentos.php através de Javascript-->
                </div>
              </div>      
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

Ou, se você não puder fazer isso, colocar no final do `<body>`, mas dentro dele:

```html
<html>
<head>

  <script src="../../assets/js/common-scripts.js"></script>

</head>

  <body>

  <section id="container" >
    <section id="main-content">
      <section class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 main-chart">
            <h3 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Indicadores</h3>
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" id="collapse11">Teste</a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse active">
                <!-- Carrega conteúdo do arquivo pa_nr_atendimentos.php através de Javascript-->
                </div>
              </div>      
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax('indicadores.php?id_indicador=1').done(function(data) {
        $("#collapse1").html(data);
      });
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

E por fim, note que eu tirei o `+` que havia nisso:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax('indicadores.php?id_indicador=1').done(function(data) {
    $("#collapse1"+).html(data); // <-- Tire esse + daqui!
  });
</script>
```

Pois esse `+` sobrando aí vai causar um erro de sintaxe no javascript!

## 5. Algumas regras sobre a estrutura de uma página HTML

Lembre-se dessas regras de ouro abaixo. Elas NUNCA devem ser violadas:

- A página deve ter um e apenas um elemento `<html>`. Não é permitido ter um elemento `<html>` dentro do outro nem que seja indiretamente.
- O elemento `<html>` só pode ter um, e apenas um `<head>` dentro dele.
- O elemento `<html>` só pode ter um, e apenas um `<body>` dentro dele.
- O elemento `<html>` não pode ter nada mais do que os elementos `<head>` e `<body>` dentro dele.
- O elemento `<head>` deve estar antes do elemento `<body>`.
- Não deve haver nada entre a tag de abertura `<html>` e a tag de abertura `<head>`.
- Não deve haver nada entre a tag de fechamento `</head>` e a tag de abertura `<body>`.
- Não deve haver nada entre a tag de fechamento `</body>` e a tag de fechamento `</html>`.
- A única coisa que pode aparecer antes da tag `<html>` é o doctype. No caso do HTML5, trata-se disso: `<!DOCTYPE html>`.
- Nada deve aparecer depois do `</html>`.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54207/discussion-on-answer-by-victor-stafusa-erro-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-ma)

Answer (score 3):

Tente fazer assim, e veja se resolve seu problema:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#collapse1").load('indicadores.php?id_indicador=2');
});
</script>
```

**Obs**: O jquery não carrega eventos se não houver um autoload antes.

[**Veja um exemplo em funcionamento**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/6fcubhdk/)

> **EDITADO:** daqui para baixo, devido à edição da pergunta:

Mesmo fazendo dessa maneira que você fez, ainda está errado, o correto seria assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $.ajax('indicadores.php?id_indicador=1').done(function(data) {
             $("#collapse1").html(data);
       });
});
```

Observe que no seu ready não está carregando uma função anônima.

Comment: Assim que estava antes de eu editar a pergunta. Apenas mudei pelas dicas aqui do pessoal. hehe

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto, você está tentando executar seu método, só que da forma que você fez, ficou indireto no `.ready(...)`, o ready não irá funcionar se você não passar um valor, variável, método ou evento.

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto, você precisa para para pensar e saber o que você precisa no seu código, se você ficar editando a sua pergunta mesmo sem ter uma solução final ao seu problema, você irá dificultar ainda mais para que as pessoas possam te ajudar e apresentar uma solução ao problema.

Answer (score 1):

@RodrigoSegatto

Os manipuladores de DOM nas versão mais novas dos browsers não estão mais dando suporte à chamadas síncronas. É exatamente isso que ele está te retornando.

Certamente, a biblioteca jQuery 1.8 deve ainda usar algum método já obsoleto e não mais suportado. Como vc mesmo testou e comentou, em browsers mais antigos funciona.

Tente atualizar para o [jQuery 1.11.3](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/releases/tag/1.11.3) (desde que seja versão 1.x, vc não deve ter problemas com breaking changes), acredito que deva resolver o problema para browser mais novos.

**UPDATE:**

Tentar outra sintaxe, talvez?

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'indicadores.php?id_indicador=1',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#collapse1").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Não deu certo Thiago. Continuou funcionando tudo, mas no console segue a mesma mensagem.

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto, fiz um update.

Answer (score 0):

Tive o mesmo problema, e com ele minha pagina recarregava sem eu solicitar.
inseri o codigo abaixo e resolveu o problema do reload.

```
e.stopPropagation();
return false;
```

Segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
var saveUsuario = function (objUsuario) {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/minhaURL",
            success: function (result) {            },
            error: function (resultErro) {           }
        });
     e.stopPropagation();
     return false;
    };
```