# Obter um html e guardar em variável

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um html simples em arquivo e quero guetarda-lo em uma variavel para usar, eu fiz o get assim:

```
 let popup = '';
 $.get( "popup.html", function( data ) {
     // the contents is now in the variable data
     console.log("data"+data);
     popup =  data;
 });
 console.log("popup"+popup);
```

Porem não esta salvando em popup, o log é:

```
    popup
(index):247 data<p style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px" id="nome">a</p>
<div class="dropdown-divider w-50 mx-auto "></div>
<p  id="endereco">c</p>
<p  id="tel">dc</p>
<p  id="email">ca</p>
```

data possui meu html, porem o popup não, estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas acho que seu problema é o let. Talvez ele não permita setar o valor no contexto de baixo. Pode ser que esteja entendendo que o popup é uma nova variável

Comment: Ou também, se a requisição for assíncrona, esse comportamento é normal. Entenda que a atribuição do valor, nesse caso, pode ocorrer depois do console.log

Comment: Esse console.log que vc mostrou na pergunta é o `console.log("data"+data);` ou `console.log("popup"+popup);`?

Comment: os 2, o popup veio antes

Comment: É porque o ajax é assíncrono... o `popup`só vai receber o valor dentro da função get

Comment: entendi, nao da pra fazer isso assincrono ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está chamando uma função *assíncrona* (`$.get`) e querendo atribuir o retorno à variável `popup` antes dela retornar algum valor. Você poderia usar o método `$.ajax` com o parâmetro `async: false`, mas não é recomendado devido ao aviso:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience
>
> **[Saiba mais neste tópico...](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48011/8063)**

O que você pode fazer é chamar uma função que retorna o valor de `data` do `$.get` após ele ser processado, usando `.then()`:

```
function htmlPopup(){
   return $.get( "popup.html").then(function(data){
      return data;
   });
}

htmlPopup().then(function(popup){
   console.log(popup);

   // resto do código que irá usar a variável popup

});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
popup = $.get( "popup.html", function( data ) { return(data)});
```

Já pega o retorno na variavel