# Array de objetos vazio

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema na criação de um array de objetos. Tenho uma função que faz uma requisição ajax e insere objetos dentro de um array num looping.

Acontece que dentro do success da requisição, o array é mostrado no console e através de um alerta da forma certa, mas fora da requisição o alert aparece como um array vazio, [].

```
        var arrayEvent = [];

        $.ajax({
            type        :   "POST",
            url         :   http_base + "/agendamento/buscaProfessor",
            data        :   {day:day, month:month, year:year},
            cache       :   false,
            dataType    :   "json",
            success :   function(data)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    data[i].data = data[i].data.replace(" ", "T");
                    var obj = {title: String(data[i].professor), start: String(data[i].data)};
                    arrayEvent.push(obj);
                }

                /*1*/alert(JSON.stringify(arrayEvent));
                /*1*/console.log(arrayEvent);
            },
            error   :   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });

        /*2*/alert(JSON.stringify(arrayEvent));
        /*2*/console.log(arrayEvent);
```

Resultado do alert do stringify do array

Dentro do success da requisição:

```
/*1*/[{"title":"Professor2","start":"2018-04-26T17:00:00"},{"title":"Professor 
1","start":"2018-04-27T17:00:00"}]
```

Fora:

```
/*2*/[]
```

Console.log

```
/*2*/[]

0:{title: "Professor2", start: "2018-04-26T17:00:00"}
1:{title: "Professor 1", start: "2018-04-27T17:00:00"}
length : 2

/*1*/(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:{title: "Professor2", start: "2018-04-26T17:00:00"}
1:{title: "Professor 1", start: "2018-04-27T17:00:00"}
length:2
```

Como poderia proceder pra resolver esse problema?

Comment: O Ajax é assíncrono. Quando o script é executado, ao chegar na linha do console.log de fora, o Ajax ainda não respondeu.

Comment: Se vc quer usar o retorno do Ajax em alguma parte do código fora do success, você deverá fazer uma requisição ao Ajax e esperar a resposta. Usando `.then` você consegue. Algo parecido com esta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/281902/8063

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. No retorno do console, os valores que retorna dos dois arrays são igual, exceto por um contar como array de um elemento só. Não seria só o caso na declaração do array que algo está incorreto?

Comment: Não entendi. Pelo que pude notar é que o console.log dentro do success retorna normal, 2 objetos na array, e fora dele não retorna nada `[]`

Comment: No console.log fora do success ele retorna como se fosse um array vazio (no alert JSON.stringify aparece []), ou de um elemento, com os objetos dentro. Dentro do success, o console.log mostra um array de 2 elementos, e o alert JSON.stringify mostra os objetos dentro do array.

Comment: Então, é o que estou falando, isso não dá certo porque o Ajax é assíncrono. Quando chega na linha do console.log fora do success, o Ajax ainda não foi processado.

Comment: Mas porque já é mostrado o resultado da requisição?

Comment: Esse resultado deve ser o que está dentro do success.

Comment: Onde eu coloco 'Console.log' na pergunta, onde tem /*2*/ corresponde ao resultado do console.log fora do success e onde tem /*1*/ corresponde ao resultado dentro do success. Como tá mostrado lá, ai ta imprimindo no console o resultado da requisição, só que o array ta com um formato diferente.

Comment: O primeiro está em formato de string, me parece, porque usou `JSON.stringify(arrayEvent)`

Comment: Os dois resultados do alert estão com Stringify. E o ultimo código, é o resultado do console.log nos dois casos.

Comment: Isso é coisa do navegador que vai puxar a array atualizada para mostrar no console, mas no JS ela está vazia naquele momento

Comment: Mas veja que mesmo assim ele informa que estava vazia no momento da execução com `[]`

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente o problema é que uma requisição http é assíncrona, por isso o browser vai passar por todo o bloco da sua função javascript, para depois ir ao servidor.

Por causa disso que o bloco abaixo não funciona.

```
    /*2*/alert(JSON.stringify(arrayEvent));
    /*2*/console.log(arrayEvent);
```

Está imprimindo array vazio, pois ainda não houve o retorno do servidor.
Para que aconteça o que você quer, deve ser utilizado o método `done`, que será executado quando a sua requisição ajax for executada com sucesso.

Segue alteração no seu código com a solução:

```
    var arrayEvent = [];

    $.ajax({
        type        :   "POST",
        url         :   http_base + "/agendamento/buscaProfessor",
        data        :   {day:day, month:month, year:year},
        cache       :   false,
        dataType    :   "json",
        success :   function(data)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                data[i].data = data[i].data.replace(" ", "T");
                var obj = {title: String(data[i].professor), start: String(data[i].data)};
                arrayEvent.push(obj);
            }

            /*1*/alert(JSON.stringify(arrayEvent));
            /*1*/console.log(arrayEvent);
        },
        error   :   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    }).done(function(){
        /*2*/alert(JSON.stringify(arrayEvent));
        /*2*/console.log(arrayEvent);   
    });
```