# Um jQuery Get() dentro de outro jQuery get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Preciso executar um `jQuery Get()` dentro de outro, mas não estou conseguindo de maneira alguma, simplesmente ignora o segundo `Get()` sem retornar o que preciso (o username do segundo `get()`):

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.mercadolibre.com/users/" + minha_id + "/order_blacklist?access_token=" + access_token, function(data){
 var employee_data ='';
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  employee_data += '<tr>';
  $.getJSON("https://api.mercadolibre.com/users/" + data[i].user.id + "?access_token=" + access_token, function(valor){
   username = valor.nickname;
   employee_data += "<td>" + username + "</td>";
  });
  employee_data += '<td>' + data[i].user.id + '</td>';
  employee_data += '<td>' + data[i].user.blocked + '</td>';
  employee_data += '</tr>';
  $('#employeed_table').append(employee_data);
 }
});
```

Comment: Existe um problema sério no seu código. Você está colocando uma requisição assíncrona dentro de um código `for`, isso é perigoso, talvez nunca funcionará o seu código desse jeito.

Answer (score 1):

Quando realizar uma requisição assíncrona você deve esperar por uma resposta. Se colocar uma requisição dentro de um `for`, inclusive com alteração de uma varíavel (como em `username = valor.nickname;`), os valores ficarão embaralhados e não funcionará do jeito que você quer.

Você pode resolver isso fazendo uma *requisição em looping*, utilizando um ponteiro e chamando uma função em laço de repitação:

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.mercadolibre.com/users/", function(data) {
   
   // cria um "for assíncrono", passando o ponteiro inicial '0', a variável 'data' e um 'callback'
   forAsync(0, data, function(employee_data){
    
    // após a função executar todas as requisições, será retornada a variável employee_data
    $('#employeed_table').append(employee_data);
    
   });
   
}); 

function forAsync(i, data, callback, employee_data = null) {
  
  if(employee_data == null) {
    employee_data = '';
  }
  
  if(data.length > 0) {
    
    employee_data += '<tr>';
    
    $.getJSON("https://api.mercadolibre.com/users/" + data[i].user.id + "?access_token=" + access_token, function(valor){
   
      var username = valor.nickname;
      
      employee_data += "<td>" + username + "</td>";
      employee_data += '<td>' + data[i].user.id + '</td>';
      employee_data += '<td>' + data[i].user.blocked + '</td>';
      employee_data += '</tr>';
      
      i++;
      
      if(i < data.length) {
        forAsync(i, data, callback, employee_data);
      }
      else {
        callback(employee_data);
      }
      
  });
    
  }
  else {
    callback(employee_data);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Talvez não seja a melhor forma de corrigir o problema e provavelmente existem métodos melhores, mas para isso você terá que revisar seu código e performá-lo para tal.

Comment: Quase deu certo, mas ele injetou somente a primeira ocorrência, debugei com console.log e está recebendo os dados corretamente, mas parece que não da tempo de injetá-los no dom a tempo, estou tentando adaptar com suas dicas, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Você tem toda razão. Ele estava pegando apenas um registro pois havia setado sempre a variável `employee_data` como `''`. Fiz a alteração, verifique se funciona!

Comment: Perfeito, valeu demais!!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo usa ajax que fica mais simples:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: api.mercadolibre.com/users/" + minha_id +"/order_blacklist?access_token=" + access_token,
    success: (response) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: api.mercadolibre.com/users/" + minha_id +"/order_blacklist?access_token=" + access_token,
            async: false,
            success: (response) => {    

            },
            error: (response) => {
              console.log('Sem sucesso');
            }
        });
    },
    error: (response) => {
      console.log('Sem sucesso');
    }
});
```

Quando você receber o retorno do primeiro GET, você faz outro GET

Comment: Maycon obrigado pela ajuda, mas aqui eu caio no mesmo problema que está dentro do laço For, mesmo com Ajax da o mesmo problema por o outro Ajax estar dentro do laço

Comment: Amigo coloca mais uma propriedade no seu ajax, async: false, que fará o seu ajax ser síncrono aí não terá mais esse problema.

Comment: @MayconF.Castro, isso talvez [não seja uma boa ideia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48011/nos-novos-navegadores-agora-não-haverá-mais-requisições-síncronas).