# Função Javascript retornando Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

Estou com um problema com uma função JavaScript. Eu preciso verificar a existência de um item no banco de dados e por isso uso uma função js com ajax chamada `verificaExistente`. O php me retorna um Json e nessa função eu verifico se existem elementos naquele retorno.
O retorno do banco está acontecendo como previsto, o problema é o `return`. Quando chamo essa função dentro do `onclick` do botão salvar, o valor retornado é `undefined`. Alguém já teve algum erro parecido? Agradeço a ajuda.

Abaixo o código:

```
$( "#btnSalvar" ).on( 'click', function(){            
    if( $( "#frmDados" ).valid() !== false ){
        if(verificaExistente()) salvar();
        else alert("Dados já existentes");            
    }
});

function verificaExistente(){        
    $.ajax({
        url: "verificaItem.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data:{ 
            id_tabela          : $("#id_tabela").val(),
            id_revestimento    : $("#id_revestimento").val(),
            operador           : 'AND'
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Erro ao Tentar ação.');
        },
        success: function( retorno ){ 
            if(retorno.dados.length > 0) return false;
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Relacionada: [função $.Ajax() retornar valor?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29382/91)

Comment: Sim. O retorno `retorno` no `success` do `$.Ajax()` vem normal. Verifiquei com um `console.log` e o valor da verificação é realmente zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que você está pegando o retorno da função `verificaExistente` e, como ela não retorna nada, o resultado é `undefined`. O que está retornando `true`/`false` é a função associada ao `success` do ajax e não a `verificaExistente`. Entretanto, a função de click não recebe o retorno da success, mas sim da função verificaExistente, que, como foi explicado anteriormente, sempre retornará undefined.

O correto seria você verificar se existe e só depois chamar uma função de retorno, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
$( "#btnSalvar" ).on( 'click', function(){            
    if( $( "#frmDados" ).valid() !== false ){
        verificaExistente()
    }
});

function verificaExistente(){        
    $.ajax({
        url: "verificaItem.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data:{ 
            id_tabela          : $("#id_tabela").val(),
            id_revestimento    : $("#id_revestimento").val(),
            operador           : 'AND'
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Erro ao Tentar ação.');
        },
        success: function( retorno ){ 
            if(retorno.dados.length > 0) alert("Dados já existentes");
            else salvar();                
        }
    });
}
```

Entretanto, o fluxo correto seria fazer essa verificação no lado do servidor apenas, usando PHP ou a tecnologia que você está usando para fazer essa validação e apenas retornar um erro, caso os dados já existam ou uma mensagem de sucesso através do ajax.

Comment: Consegui entender o raciocino, mas os `return true` ou `return false` não fariam a verificação no `if` funcionar?

Comment: Como eu disse, ele não tá retornando nada, vou editar pra ficar melhor essa parte da explicação...

Comment: Puts. Funcionou legal. Eu achava que os `return false` e  `return true` dentro do `success` seria repassado para a minha função. Valeu a ajuda @Felipe Avelar.

Answer (score 1):

Tens de ter em conta que uma chamada AJAX é assincrona e o resultado que pretendes vai aparecer dentro da função success. Quando corres a função `verificaExistente` ele vai iniciar o AJAX que vai correr paralelamente e acabar a função sem esperar pelo ajax.

O que sugiro é fazeres uma callback. Por exemplo:

```
$( "#btnSalvar" ).on( 'click', function(){            
    if( $( "#frmDados" ).valid() !== false ){
        verificaExistente(function(retorno ){
             if(retorno.dados.length > 0) return alert("Dados já existentes");
             salvar();
        });
    }
});

function verificaExistente(fn){        
    $.ajax({
        url: "verificaItem.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data:{ 
            id_tabela          : $("#id_tabela").val(),
            id_revestimento    : $("#id_revestimento").val(),
            operador           : 'AND'
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Erro ao Tentar ação.');
        },
        success: fn // usa a callback aqui
    });
}
```

Dessa maneira passas a função e o que queres fazer para a resposta do AJAX, que será executado quando o servidor responder.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma seria você criar um outro método e passar o valor para ele dentro do       "success", e assim ter o que deseja.

Exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    url : site,
    type : 'GET',
    success : function(x) {
    //Faz algo  
    metodoX(valor); //Aqui você chama outro método e passa o valor retornado do ajax.
    }
});

function metodoX(valor){
console.log(valor);
}
```

Lembrando que isso não é uma boa prática.