# como ler as variaveis de retorno usando json curl e php

Tags: php, json

Meu problema refere-se a integraço com a cielo e já revirei tudo, mas sem sucesso.

Li esta postagem:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54039/na-api-da-cielo-em-php

"entendi" o que disse na postagem e fiz assim:

```
<?
//string json contendo os dados de um funcionário
$request = '{
    "MerchantOrder":"2014111703",
    "Customer":{
    "Name":"Comprador crédito simples"
},
"Payment":{
    "Type":"CreditCard",
    "Amount":15700,
    "Installments":1,
    "Descriptor":"123456789ABCD",
    "CreditCard":{
        "Holder":"Teste Holder",
        "ExpirationDate":"12/2030",
        "SecurityCode":"123",
        "Brand":"Visa"
    }
 }
}';

$data_string = json_encode($request, false);

$ch = curl_init("https://apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/1/sales");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELD, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTPPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'MerchantId: ' . $MerchantID,
    'MerchantKey: ' . $MerchantKey,
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($datastring))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, false);

echo "$result->ProofOfSale";
echo "$result->Tid";
echo "$result->Authorization";
echo "$result->SoftDescriptor";
echo "$result->ECI";
echo "$result->Status";
echo "$result->ReturnCode";
echo "$result->ReturnMessage";
?>
```

A parte final refere-se as variáveis de retorno que a cielo informa conforte este manual:

Mas nao retorna nada.

Realmente não entendo nada de json e como ele funciona no php.

Se puder me ajudar, ficaria muito agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

[Veja ista resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4413/15089) O problema está em `json_decode($result, true)`, após o CURL, você tem duas opções:

---

1. Mude para `json_decode($result)` e mantenha o resto como está; ou
2. Mantenha o `json_decode($result, true)` e mude os `$result->ProofOfSale` para `$result['ProofOfSale']`, assim como os outros, por exemplo.

*Além disso faça um  `var_dump($result)` para saber como estão os dados e se eles realmente estão "chegando".*

Answer (score 0):

Tente enviar o seu json no formato de `array`. Você está utilizando o `json_encode`, a função dele é transformar um array em json, por isso tente usar a `json_decode`:

```
<?php
//string json contendo os dados de um funcionário
$request = '{
    "MerchantOrderId":"2014111703",
    "Customer":{
    "Name":"Comprador crédito simples"
},
"Payment":{
    "Type":"CreditCard",
    "Amount":15700,
    "Installments":1,
    "SoftDescriptor":"123456789ABCD",
    "CreditCard":{
        "CardNumber":"1234123412341231",
        "Holder":"Teste Holder",
        "ExpirationDate":"12/2030",
        "SecurityCode":"123",
        "Brand":"Visa"
    }
 }
}';

$data_string = json_decode($request, true);

$MerchantID="meuid";
$MerchantKey="meukey";

$ch = curl_init("https://apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/1/sales");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'MerchantId: ' . $MerchantID,
    'MerchantKey: ' . $MerchantKey,
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

echo "$result->ProofOfSale";
echo "$result->Tid";
echo "$result->AuthorizationCode";
echo "$result->SoftDescriptor";
echo "$result->PaymentId";
echo "$result->ECI";
echo "$result->Status";
echo "$result->ReturnCode";
echo "$result->ReturnMessage";
?>
```

Verifique essa linha também `$result = json_decode($result, true);`, pois se a cielo estiver lhe mandando um array, você tem que utilizar a função `json_encode` pois abaixo dessa linha você está exibindo o retorno como objeto.