# Return True ou False no Success do jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btnEnviarDados').click(function() {

      var strFomr = $("form").serialize();

      $.ajax({
        url: $("form").submit(),
        type: "POST",
        data: strFomr,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cache: false,
        success: function(ret) {
          if (ret == true) {
            alert('funcionaou');
            location.href = "@Url.Action("
            Contact ")"
          } else
            alert("noa funcionou a rquisicao");
        }
      });
    });
  }) < /script>
```

Meu *Controller*:

```
 public JsonResult CadastroUsuario(Usuario _usuario )
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json(new{ret = true });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { ret = true });
        }            
    }
```

o problema é que na *View* retorna apenas o valor `true` ou `false` como mostra a imagem, e eu queria que o retorno fosse no `success` do `jquery`.

[image: Retorno do jQuery]

Alguém tem algum ideia de como retorno o valor `true` ou `false` no `success` do jQuery para exibir um `alert` do retorno?

Comment: Possível duplicidade: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29382/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-retornar-valor

Comment: Creio que o correto seria algo como: `success: function(data) {
          if (data.ret == true) {`

Answer (score 4):

Tente fazer da seguinte forma: no JS, valide direto o objeto retornado e no C# retorne o `boolean` direto sem criar um objeto pra armazenar esse valor. Como no exemplo que deixei abaixo e veja se funciona:

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btnEnviarDados').click(function() {

      var strFomr = $("form").serialize();

      $.ajax({
        
        type: "POST",
        url: $("form").submit(),
        data: strFomr,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          if (data) {
            alert('Valor de retorno é verdadeiro!');
          } else
            alert("Valor de retorno é falso!");
        }
      });
    });
  }) 
< /script>
```

```
    public JsonResult CadastroUsuario(Usuario _usuario )
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json(true);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(false);
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Faria menor ainda: `public JsonResult CadastroUsuario(Usuario _usuario ) { return ModelState.IsValid; }`.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa colocar o atributo `[HttpPost]` em cima do seu método.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CadastroUsuario(Usuario _usuario )
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json(new{ret = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { ret = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Da forma que está tentando usar o retorno de Ajax não funciona.
O ideal é externar este resultado e trabalhar com ele do "lado de fora".
Abaixo está uma demonstração, "**não testada**" de como acoplar a função Ajax.
Tenha certeza de que os dados a serem enviados estão corretos e o endereço do "**webService**".

```
var ajaxParams  = {
    type:   'POST',
    data:   $('form').serialize (),
    url:    $('form').submit (),
    contentType:    'json',
    cache:  false
};

var httpRequest =   function (params, fn) {
    $.ajax ({
        type:   params.type,
        data:   params.data,
        contentType:    params.contentType,
        cache:  params.cache,
        url:    params.url
        success:    function (jsonData) {
            fn (jsonData);
        }
    });
};


$('#btnEnviarDados').bind ('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault ();

    httpRequest (ajaxParams, function (jsonObject) {
        if (jsonObject) {
            console.log ('funcionou...')
        }
        else {
            console.log ('Há algo errado aqui...');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
        url: $("form").submit(),
        type: "POST",
        data: strFomr,
        //Retire isso. contentType diz o formato enviando para o servidor
        //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //Use dataType que diz o formato esperado de resposta
        dataType: 'JSON',
        cache: false,
        //success: function(ret) {
        success: function(resposta) {
          //if (ret == true) {
          if (resposta.ret == true) {
            alert('funcionaou');
            location.href = "@Url.Action("
            Contact ")"
          } else
            alert("noa funcionou a rquisicao");
        }
      });
```

contentType: define o tipo de dados que está sendo enviado para o servidor. O padrão é `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, que é adequado para a maioria dos casos.

dataType: define o formato de resposta que você esta esperando receber do servidor. Pode ser `text`, `xml`, `html`, `script`, `json`, `jsonp`. Se nenhum valor for informado, jQuery vai tentar deduzir com base no MIME type da resposta.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Seria interessante traduzir o quadro amarelo, pois nem todos que visitam o site podem entender inglês.

Comment: @diegofm, desculpe. Editei e incluí a tradução.