# funcao para utilizar dados da query

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

estou construindo uma função que via ajax faz a consulta de uma query no banco e via json me retorna o resultado. Porém tudo funciona mais nao consigo utilizar o objeto json em nenhum outro lugar exceto dentro da funcao.

ja tentei usar variavel global declarada dentro e fora da funcao, return e nada da certo. segue o codigo.

```
var sqls;
function sql(query){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/lookup.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {query: query},
  success:function(dados){
   sqls = dados;   

    }
    });
return sqls;
};
```

se eu dou um alert(sqls.informacao_que_quero); a mensagem aparece undefined porem se eu colocar o alert dentro da funcao sql funciona normalmente.

preciso ter acesso desse json em qualquer lugar do script

Comment: Já tem bastante material na comunidade sobre isso!

Comment: Veja se esta questão te ajuda! Inclusive a respondi também!
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182500/return-true-ou-false-no-success-do-jquery

Answer (score 2):

É o velho problema do javascript assincrono. Vamos supor que a todo o processo de conexao demora cerca de 2 segundos.

Quando voce chama a função `sql(query)` o bloco `success` so vai ser chamado 2 segundos depois (lembrando que esse tempo e somente um exemplo), porem o resto do código continua normalmente, quando chega no seu `return sqls` você ainda não obteve a resposta do servidor, por isso o alert dentro do `success` funciona e fora não.

O `success` vai esperar ate o servidor responder com sucesso, e só ai ele é chamado.

Experimenta colocar um `console.log()` antes do `return sqls` e um dentro do `success`, vai perceber que dentro do success vai vai sempre ser chamado depois.

O que voce precisa fazer é colocar o código que depende do `sqls` dentro do bloco `success`.

#### ASYNC false

Pode tambem usar a opcao `async: false` do jquery, mas o problema disso é que vai "travar" o brower enquanto a requisicao nao terminar, isso por que a requisicao é feita na mesma thread, por isso se usa ele asincrono.

```js
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
 var sqls;
 function sql(query){
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {},
   async: false,
   success:function(dados){
    sqls = dados;
    console.log('callback');
   }
  });
  
   console.log('fim da funcao');
  return sqls;
 }
 
 sql('SELECT * FROM table;');
 console.log('resultado', sqls);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ja tentei deixa sincrono usando a opção  async: false. a questao e poder acessar as informações do objeto json fora da funcao sql porque dentro das suas {} funciona o problema e fora dela

Comment: nao sei exatamente o que esta aconteceno nem como esta acessando os dados fora da funcao, mas editei e coloquei um exemplo com `async:false`. Pode obervar que o log vem na ordem correta e os dados tambem.

Answer (score -1):

Parece-me que o principal problema passa por estar a tentar uma abordagem de programação clássica síncrona usando jquery, que neste caso de uso em particular, usa uma abordagem assíncrona via uso de callbacks. Recomendo a leitura de um 101 sobre chamadas assíncronas usando callbacks (funções de retorno).

A função ajax, por exemplo, permite distintas sintaxes que podem simplificar a leitura. Por exemplo, nesta situação, o callbacks de sucesso pode ser adicionado à chamada de forma póstuma (decorando a função); algo como:

```
'$.ajax(...).success(function callbackSucesso(dados) { ... });
```

Programar com chamadas assíncronas requer mudança de paradigma. Deixa de fazer sentido a abordagem de guardar variáveis globais e tentar aceder-lhes de qualquer sítio e, principalmente, em qualquer altura.